# How to record landscape video using portrait device

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-recording

How can I record a landscape video using a device that is in portrait orientation?

This means that previewLayer width > height

`AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft` is not right.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50799821/2276920

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample project of iOS in developer.apple.com
[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html)

You need to use AVAssetWriter AVAssetWriterInput

You need to be focus in this method in the MovieRecorder.m

```
- (void)addVideoTrackWithSourceFormatDescription:(CMFormatDescriptionRef)formatDescription transform:(CGAffineTransform)transform settings:(NSDictionary *)videoSettings
```

You need to edit the code to do that