# How to record landscape video in a portrait application? (Swift 2, iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, xcode7

I need to record a landscape video inside my portrait iPhone application.

Is it possible or is it blocked by any hardware limitation?

Using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer I was able to change the preview orientation, but the video is still recorded in Portrait.

Any idea is welcomed!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the orientation to landscape for the video recording. And set the preview layer to portrait to achieve a landscape video that is previewed in portrait. If I understand your question correctly. Can you show any code you tried already?

```
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
            let connection = videoOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
            if connection.supportsVideoOrientation {
                connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight
            }
            print("adding output")

        } else {
            print("Could not add front video output")
            return
        }

    ...

    func setupPreviewLayer() {

        ...etc...

        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait

        ...etc...

    }
```

Comment: I tryed to use the previewLayer connection, but it didn't work (I received a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error).

Comment: could you show some code how you set up your preview layer?

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem playing landscape video in portrait application. Solved it by writing the following code. Add the following code on configuring session:

```
captureSession.addOutput(videoFileOutput)
let videoDataOuputConnection = videoFileOutput.connection(with: .video)
videoFileOutput.setRecordsVideoOrientationAndMirroringChangesAsMetadataTrack(true, for: videoDataOuputConnection!)
```

In start recording video function, Add the following code before starting to record:

```
let videoDataOuputConnection = videoFileOutput.connection(with: .video)
let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
videoDataOuputConnection!.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: orientation.rawValue)!
```

Note: videoFileOutput is of type AVCaptureMovieFileOutput, captureSession is of type AVCaptureSession